# JBoss Fuse, Apache Karaf: how to get the info that the certain osgi bundle is started in runtime?

Tags: apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse

I need your advice in followed:
We have several adapters (bundles) and they have certain priority to be used in application business logic.
To manage them the administrator will just switch them on or off.
I'm looking the way for the correct defining is the bundle starts or not in runtime.
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Karaf 3.0.x, using the CLI and assuming you know part of the bundle's name (manifest.mf header Bundle-Name) or symbolic name (manifest.mf header Bundle-SymbolicName), you can access the status with the following commands:

Login to the Karaf console:

```
$ ssh karaf@localhost -p 8101
```

Then

```
karaf@root()> bundle:list -s|grep {symbolic-name}
```

or

```
karaf@root()> bundle:list |grep {name}
```

E.g.

```
karaf@root()> bundle:list -s |grep -i jackson-core-asl
109 | Active   |  80 | 1.9.13  | jackson-core-asl
```